# A pointer outside a structure and a pointer inside a structure point to same array and have different stored address

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

I am trying to set up a structure array that stores the address from elements in a 2-dimensional array named map.
I can get an address to be stored in the structure members, but it is not the address of the map array.

I was able to store address values inside FIELD[][].pos and set the char value in FIELD[][].symbol and print them to screen.  But when I tried to print the values in map[][] to the screen they didn't match. 
So I added int *map_ptr = &map[0][0], and it turns out that the address I have from map_ptr does not match the address I have from FIELD[0][0].pos and I do not understand why they would be different.

struct field is able to successfully store an address value in FIELD[i][j].pos, and FIELD[i][j].pos = &FIELD[i][j].symbol seemed to work as intended. But when I printed out map[][] to screen directly from map[][] and also from FIELD I got disparate results. So I added int *map_ptr = &map[0][0] to compare pointer addresses and it turns out that the addresses in my FIELD[][].pos do not match the actual address for map[][].

```
char map[5][5];
map[0][0] = '#';
char *map_ptr = &map[0][0];
printf("map_ptr = %d, %d, %c\n", &map_ptr, *map_ptr, *map_ptr);
printf("\n");

struct field
{
    char *pos;
    char symbol;
}FIELD[5][5];

for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
        FIELD[i][j].pos = &map[i][j];
        FIELD[i][j].symbol = '#';
        FIELD[i][j].pos = &FIELD[i][j].symbol;
    }
}

/* Prints memory address FIELD[i][j].pos */
printf("Address from struct field FIELD[i][j].pos = ");
printf("%d \n", FIELD[0][0].pos)
```

The address in map_ptr and FIELD[0][0].pos should be the same, and they should point to the address for map[0][0], but they do not.

Here is my printout of the address values:`
map_ptr = 6422256, 35, #

Address from struct field FIELD[i][j].pos = 6422060`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that you're not printing where `map_ptr` is pointing (that would be the value of `map_ptr`), but the location (address) of the variable `map_ptr`. Drop the address-of operator in your call.

Another problem is that you reassign `FIELD[i][j].pos`, making it point to `FIELD[i][j].symbol`. I'm *guessing* that the assignment really should be

```
*FIELD[i][j].pos = FIELD[i][j].symbol;
```

Also note that you should use the format `"%p"` to print a (`void *`, cast is really needed) pointer, mismatching format specifier and argument type lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

You have re-assigned FIELD[i][j].pos to &FIELD[i][j].symbol